# Key Q–O (QWERTYUIO) isn't working

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

Suddenly, some of the keys (Q to O) isn't working. I don't have any idea what wrong I have done. Only Q, W, E, R, T, Y, U, I, O aren't working. All others keys working fine. Anyone have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Funny, I had to go to the Apple store today to get a replacement for my keyboard because the p-key didn't work anymore. They exchanged it for free.

Comment: Try another keyboard and see if that works ok

Comment: I am using an external keyboard and it's working fine.